# Android OkHttp request params are not added to the request

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm using [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding) to get the longitude of a location given by the user. Since Geocoder is not that reliable I decided to use OkHttp to send some http requests.

```
val baseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
        val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
            .add("address", address)
            .add("key", "API KEY")
            .add("region", "CA")
            .build()
        var request = Request.Builder()
            .url(baseUrl)
            .post(formBody)
            .build()
        Log.d("address request", request.toString())
```

I use `FormBody.Builder().add(key,value)` to add params to the request but the `request.toString()` prints out `baseUrl` which seems that the params are not added via Builder().add().
This is the response.

```
{"error_message" : "Invalid request. Missing the 'address', 'components', 'latlng' or 'place_id' parameter.",
       "results" : [],
       "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"}
```

Where am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the docs, it seems that `address`, `key`, and `region` are query parameters, but you are submitting these parameters in the request body.

You can use `HttpUrl.addQueryParameter()` to add query parameters to your URL.

Example (okhttp 4.x):

```kotlin
val url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json".toHttpUrl().newBuilder()
    .addQueryParameter("address", "prueba")
    .addQueryParameter("key", "API KEY")
    .addQueryParameter("region", "CA")
    .build()

val request = Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .build()
```